# Converting csv values to table in R

Tags: r, parsing, csv, split

I have some data from a poll which looks like this:

```
                                    Freetime_activities
1                       Travelling, On the PC, Clubbing
2                           Sports, On the PC, Clubbing
3                                              Clubbing
4                                             On the PC
5                       Travelling, On the PC, Clubbing
6                                             On the PC
7                               Watching TV, Travelling
```

I want to get the count of each value (how many times Travelling/On the PC/etc.), but I'm having trouble splitting the values. Is there a function in R that can do for example:

```
split("A,B,C") -> 
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

Or is there a straight forward solution to counting the values directly from the column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split the column by the delimiter `", "`), `unlist` the `list` output and then use `table` to get the frequency

```
 tbl <- table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df1$Freetime_activities),
                                          ", ")))
 as.data.frame(tbl)
 #         Var1 Freq
 #1    Clubbing    4
 #2   On the PC    5
 #3      Sports    1
 #4  Travelling    3
 #5 Watching TV    1
```

NOTE: Here is used `as.character` in case the column is a `factor` as `strsplit` can take only `character` vectors.

Or another option would be to use `scan` to extract the elements, and then with `table` get the frequency.

```
 table(trimws(scan(text = as.character(df1$Freetime_activities),
                   what = "", sep = ",")))
```

Or using `read.table` with `unlist` and `table`

```
table(unlist(read.table(text = as.character(df1$Freetime_activities), 
           sep = ",", fill = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)))
```

EDIT: Based on @David Arenburg's comments.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Freetime_activities = c("Travelling, On the PC, 
  Clubbing", 
"Sports, On the PC, Clubbing", "Clubbing", "On the PC", "Travelling, 
 On the PC, Clubbing", 
"On the PC", "Watching TV, Travelling")), 
 .Names = "Freetime_activities", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: this has some undesired effects ->  Var1 Freq
1    \n"On the PC    1
2  \n"Watching TV    1
3      "Clubbing"    1
4      "On the PC    5
5     "On the PC"    8

Comment: @MarioStoilov  I am not sure I understand the undesired effects.  Based on the example you showed, I get the frequency as you described.

Comment: I am saying that I get various variables, which should be the same, like (\n"On the PC, "On the PC, "On the PC")

Comment: Seems that as.character is behaving badly -> as.character(myData[4])
[1] "c(\"Travelling,On the PC,Clubbing\", \"Sports,On the PC,Clubbing\",....

Comment: I should point out that I'm reading the data from an excel sheet

Comment: @MarioStoilov  `myData[4]` is still a `data.frame` with a single column.  You need `myData[[4]]` or `myData[,4]`.  Also, if you are reading from excel sheet, you would be using `read_excel` from `library(readxl)` or other packages that reads excel sheets.

Comment: @MarioStoilov If you do the same thing with my example data, it reproduce the problem , i..e `as.character(df1[1])#[1] "c(\"Travelling, On the PC, Clubbing\", \"...`. Instead, it should be `as.character(df1[,1])`